# Warning in strings.xml

Tags: android

I am wondering about a warning I get in my strings.xml file.

The very first line:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

has a warning indicator that says `The resource R.string.hello appears to be 
 unused`.

Why am I getting this error? No where in the code do I have 'hello' as confirmed by a simple grep for it.

**NOTE: there is NO string of characters that spell out hello in the project. Not in the java files, not in the xml files, not any in any of the other files that grep would look at. That is why I am so confused by this warning.**

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project? I'd even try manually deleting the `gen` folder containing `R.java`.

Comment: kichik, yeah, done that already. But it is still there. I am wondering if there is an issue with the Lint implementation?

Comment: just a warning not a big deal, if it is really annoying you, try remove it from strings.xml then do a clean build and see what happen.

Comment: yorkw, thanks for the tip but there is no such string in the strings.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same Problem. This string resource was nowhere to be found but yet still I had the error Message.

Solution:
Right click on your Project -> Android tools -> clear LINT markers worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

The hello resource seems to be created for every new Android application just as the `@drawable/ic_launcher`. Do you have any other projects in your workspace?

I had a library project which was in the same workspace and it produced the same warning message. I deleted the resources in the library project and the warning message disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

> > [...] has a warning indicator that says The resource R.string.hello appears to be **unused**.
>
> Why am I getting this error? **No where in the code do I have 'hello'** as confirmed by a simple grep for it.

Emphasized it a bit. That's just a warning from the new android [lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) tool, stating that this particular string is not in use and you can delete it from your *strings.xml* to clean up your files a bit. Or ignore the warning.

If you already deleted that string from *strings.xml* and the warning persists, try running the lint checks again *(`Window -> Run Android Lint`)*.

Comment: Thanks alextsc. But as I said, nowhere in the code, xml files, anywhere is there a string of characters that spell out hello. And, since it is nowhere in any of the files, it is unused yes. But since it doesn't exist anywhere in the any of the files in that project, it shouldn't come up in first place. :)

Comment: Oh, and it has never been in any of the files since this code was put on laptop. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project from Project>Clean..

Answer (score 0):

A proper fix for this eve though it is older is this:
[NOTE Filenames are not exact in most cases, just a guide]

```
1. In your fragment_main.xml[or activity_main.xml for older API] (/ProjectName/res/layout/fragment_main.xml)
change your view and add this: 
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <!-- Add this one line below as "contentDescription" refers to this issue 
         of description not found warning by Lint -->
    android:contentDescription="@string/description"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

2. The @string references the strings in your strings.xml and the name 
   of the string itself is "description"
   So in your ProjectName/res/values/strings.xml add:

   <string name="description">Variables</string>
```